# Why does my mac drop connection to my network regularly

Tags: mac, network, wifi

I have had my macbook air for almost a year with no problems however over the last couple of weeks it keeps dropping its connection to my network on a regular basis. The only way to fix it is for me to turn Wi-Fi off then on again, then it works again fine - for a while - then the same thing happens all over again. It is very frustrating.

If I ping my router's IP address I get a valid response while it's working but while it wont connect to the network I get "Request timeout for icmp_seq".

No other computers / phones that connect to the Wi-Fi are affected by this problem, it is only my mac.

This is driving me crazy, I've tried stuff on other forums where people have had similar problems but have had no luck. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: So we do not waist time here, please elaborate what have you tried so far.

Comment: You question can not be answered without you providing more information since it could be number of reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed your network settings at any point? If so you may need to set the network to automatic and renew DHCP. Please see the instructions here: http://www.technobezz.com/mac-wont-connect-to-wifi/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  A couple of things...this is better as a comment as it really doesn't answer the OP's question.  Secondly, link only answers are not advisable because when the link goes stale (and they do) the answer is no longer useful.  It's best to summarize it and provide the link as reference.  Have a look at our Help Center - [How to Write a Good Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)